# How can I dynamically update search results based on form input in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I want site visitors to be able to view nearby shows within a radius that can be input via dropdown form. I have a view that displays nearby shows using the Geocoder gem:

```
<h3> Shows near <%= request.location.city %> </h3>
<%= form_for @nearby_shows.first do |f| %>
<p> Radius (in miles): <%= f.select(:radii, [10,20,30,40,50], {},
   :style => "width:50px", :selected => f.object.radii, :onchange =>
   "location.href = '#{shows_path}'") %> </p>
<% end %>
<ul class="users">
  <% @nearby_shows.each do |nearby_show| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to nearby_show.show_name, nearby_show %>
    </li>
  <% end %>
</ul>
```

Right now the selection doesn't affect anything, and the selection isn't remembered in the form when the page refreshes.

The model, show.rb contains:

```
attr_accessor :radii
```

And the shows controller contains:

```
def index
    @shows = Show.all
    @radii = 50
    @nearby_venues = Venue.near("Boulder, CO",@radii,:select =>
    "id").to_a
    @nearby_shows = Show.where(show_venue: @nearby_venues)
end
```

In production, I'll be using request.location.city, but in development I'm just using "Boulder, CO" as an example.

How can I set @radii using the input select form? I am concerned that form_for will not permit me to change a variable for the list of entities @nearby_shows.

Comment: I'm not sure I really understand... do you want an AJAX solution ?

Comment: Yes, that would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If you want a fast AJAX solution, here's what I would do

First, add an ID to your list so it's easy to manipulate

```
<ul id="my_id" class="users"></ul>
```

I really don't understand why you need that `<%= form_for @nearby_shows.first %>` for ? If I understand well, you just want to show a select, and update the list of nearby shows based on what the user selects ?

**routes.rb**

```
resource :shows do
  get 'update_nearby', on: :collection, constraints: { format: 'js' }
end
# GET /shows/update_nearby, meant to be used only with AJAX
```

**your_view.html.erb**

```
<%= form_tag update_nearby_shows_path, remote: :true do |f| %>
<p> Radius (in miles): <%= select_tag(:radii, [10,20,30,40,50], {},
   :style => "width:50px", :selected => @radii, :onchange =>
   "location.href = '#{shows_path}'") %> </p>
<% end %>

<!-- On Submit, it will request a JS response 
     You can add some JS to submit the form everytime the select changes -->
```

Add some JS specific respone

**your_controller.rb**

```
def update_nearby
  find_nearby_shows
end

private
def find_nearby_shows
  @radii = params[:radii] ? params[:radii] : 50
  @nearby_venues = Venue.near("Boulder, CO",@radii,:select =>
    "id").to_a
  @nearby_shows = Show.where(show_venue: @nearby_venues)
end
```

**update_nearby.js.erb**

```
<% if @nearby_shows %>
  // Empty the list
  var id = $("#my_id").empty()
  <% @nearby_shows.each do %>
    // Add one <li> per show
    $("<li>", { 'html': "<%= escape_javascript(link_to(nearby_show.show_name, nearby_show)) %>"}).appendTo(id)
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Bonus : you said you wanted to save the radius ? You can actually try to add it to the user session

```
def index
  ...
  @radii = session[:saved_radii] ? session[:saved_radii] : DEFAULT_RADIUS
  ...
end

def update_nearby
   find_nearby_shows
   session[:saved_radii] = @radii
end
```

But if you really want to save it for the user, you should have a `preferred_radii` field in your User model

Comment: Thank you for this! I'm getting an error trying to implement it, but the idea is just what I wanted. There seems to be something wrong with the syntax of select_tag. Rails gives a "too many arguments" error.

Comment: If I change the syntax to: select_tag(:radii, options_for_select( [10,20,30,40,50] ), :style => "width:50px", :selected => @radii, :onchange => "location.href = '#{shows_path}'"), then the view loads, but the selection does not seem to work. I can change the selection, but it refreshes back to the default (10), and the results are not using a 10 mile radius, they appear to still be using a 50 mile radius.

Comment: Also, if I remove the @nearby_shows, @nearby_venues, and @radii definitions from the index section of the controller, I get an "undefined method `each' for nil:NilClass" error.

Comment: Yeah sorry, my `select_tag` syntax is completely off because I'm using some gem that overrides it ^^". I believe the `selected` radii should go as an argument of `options_for_select`. I can help you more in like 12H, but if you want some leads in the meantime : you need to change the `onchange` callback so it will actually submit the form when you select a different option. In your index, the "bonus" session stuff was just something to improve your current @radii initialization, you still need to initialize the other variables like your already did..

Comment: Are the changes in the bonus section supposed to go in the shows_controller or elsewhere? I made changes to the default radii in 'options_for_select', and all the other changes you suggested, and the page still doesn't refresh with the new selected value, it reverts back to the default on refresh. The values in '@radii' seem to be working to sort the results, but the selection in the form doesn't affect '@radii' from what I can tell.

Comment: We are indeed talking about the same controller. Hmm can you check what happens with a debugger ? I'm using [byebug](https://github.com/deivid-rodriguez/byebug) and it's really cool. Just add it to your gemfile#development_group, and write `byebug` in your code. It will spawn a debugger in your console, and you can check the value of `session[:savd_radii]`